# Responsive Google AdSense has display:none, but HTML still renders the same?

Tags: html, css, adsense, responsive-interaction

I am implementing responsive Google AdSense ad unit, and I would like to hide an ad on <768px.

I saw on https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3543893#hide that it is allowed now to use CSS `display:none` on specific media query. However, when I apply that, the HTML is still the same.

How should I implement the AdSense code so that Google won't inject the content if a user opens the site on screen <768px?

Comment: Your HTML will always be the same. The rendering however will be different. Do you have experience with responsive design?

Comment: What I meant is, google still inject the image ad. I want to make sure that google only inject the code when it's > 768px.

Answer (score 0):

I think we already know the official "*Hiding an ad unit*" snippet, and we know it works fine.

The problem might be your implementation, and you should probably provide your snippet. (Without your publisher ID is OK.)

Something like this could be what you want:

```
<style type="text/css">
.adslot_1_768plus { display: inline-block; width: 728px; height: 90px; }
@media (max-width: 767px) { .adslot_1_768plus { display: none; } }
</style>
<ins class="adsbygoogle adslot_1_768plus"
   data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234"
   data-ad-slot="5678"></ins>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>
```

Comment: @ivanasetiawan - Sorry, "_I still see <img />_" doesn't make much difference: we still don't know how your code looks like. Feel free to edit your original message and to include your code (remove your pubID if you want). Btw. - did you try snippet from my message?

Comment: @ivanasetiawan - It might be worth to mention - if _the ad is **hidden**, but still **rendered**_, you should remove that code from your site. What you described is a policy violation [(link)](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736?hl=en), and I think Google AdSense could take action against your account because of that.

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear..

I am implementing responsive ad, and my goal is to only make sure that google loads the ad when user’s screen is > 768px. 

This means, if a user opens the site on mobile, the ad won’t show - not only hidden via CSS but also making sure that google won’t load the ad on the page. 

So far when I implement media query with "display: none" and inspect the element on screen < 768px, I still see that google injects the code.

I fixed it by checking data-advertisement-maxwidth and running the "ad function" when on condition applied. 

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: @ivanasetiawan Few different variants are considered "responsive" ad code in AdSense. Only if I know how your code looks like, I could _try_ to help. You said [this - (click here)](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3543893#hide) doesn't work. I can tell you I'm 100.1% sure it works, and your implementation is probably the problem.